# Prolog Sorting a List with each position having two elements

Tags: prolog

I am currently working on Prolog quick sorting.

The quicksort rule in Prolog is:

```
quick_sort2(List, Sorted) :- 
   q_sort(List, [], Sorted).

q_sort([], Acc, Acc).
q_sort([H|T], Acc, Sorted) :-
   pivoting(H, T, L1, L2), 
   q_sort(L1, Acc, Sorted1),
   q_sort(L2, [H|Sorted1], Sorted).

pivoting(H, [], [], []).
pivoting(H, [X|T], L, [X|G]) :-X =< H, pivoting(H, T, L, G).
pivoting(H, [X|T], [X|L], G) :-X  > H, pivoting(H, T, L, G).
```

It sorts lists that look like this: `[1,2,5,3,4]`

However, my list currently is in this format with each position having 2 elements:

`[(18427840,wplabuan), (801267209,johor), (258368353,kelantan), (381775777,kedah), (443783415,sabah), (188532090,melaka), (540920146,wpkualalumpur), (380758940,pulaupinang), (285145365,pahang), (1447204206,selangor), (243650261,negerisembilan), (47633359,perlis), (455013525,perak), (26449297,wpputrajaya), (204709755,terengganu), (498580177,sarawak)]`

May I know how should I sort the list above using quicksort?

Thank you.

I want the list with sum and state (sum, state) to be sorted in ascending order according to the sum.

Answer (score 1):

The goal [`E1 =< E2`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%3D%3C)/2) succeeds iff the **number** denoted by the arithmetic expression `E1` is less than or equal to the **number** denoted by the arithmetic expression `E2`. For example:

```
?- 2*3 =< 9-1.
true.

?- 6 =< 3.
false.
```

Note, however, that the operator `=<` cannot be used to compare **structures**:

```
?- (2,b) =< (3,a).
ERROR: Arithmetic: `b/0' is not a function
...
```

To compare structures, w.r.t. the [standard order of terms](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=standardorder), you can use the operator `@=<`:

```
?- (2,b) @=< (3,a).
true.                % because 2 does precede 3 in the standard order of terms

?- (7,a) @=< (5,b).
false.               % because 7 does not precede 5 in the standard order of terms

?- (2,b) @=< (2,c).
true.                % because both structures start with 2 and b does precede c

?- (2,b) @=< (2,a).  
false.               % because both structures start with 2 but b does not precede a
```

Analogously, when comparing structures, you can also use operators `@<`, `@>`, `@>=`.

Thus, to solve the problem, you can modify your code as follows:

```
pivoting(_, [], [],[]).
pivoting(H, [X|T], L, [X|G]) :- X @=< H, pivoting(H, T, L, G).
pivoting(H, [X|T], [X|L],G)  :- X @>  H, pivoting(H, T, L, G).
```